# How to resolve "Cannot retrieve .Id from docker" when building Docker image using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a Jenkins pipeline to build a Dockerfile.

The dockerfile successfully goes through all steps, and creates the docker image.

As shown:

```
Step 16/19 : FROM base AS final
 ---> <id>
Step 17/19 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> <id>
Step 18/19 : COPY --from=publish /app .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> <id>
Step 19/19 : ENTRYPOINT ["", "myapp.dll"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> <id>
Successfully built cb3y81938e88
Successfully tagged myapp:latest
```

However, after this, the shell Fails with the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot retrieve .Id from 'docker inspect base AS final'
```

Why does it throw this error despite the docker image successfully built? 
When I execute this on my local machine, the command exits on "Successfully tagged myapp:latest"

My docker version is 18.03.1-ce.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My guess would be that the Jenkins Docker plugin(s) are not properly supporting multi-stage Docker builds.

Comment: There is a PR solving this here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/pull/162

You can build the plugin and load it manually until a maintainer checks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in that Jenkins plugin.

You can try removing multi stage build name ("`AS final`" as you don't need it):

```
FROM base
(....)
```

But if you really need to reference a previous built image (multi stage), a workaround can be using `--copy-from 0` (0,1,2 as it corresponds, instead of the alias name)

Related issues in Jenkins

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44789
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44609
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31507

---

**Edit**

Documenting here the solution found by the OP:

> I got this working by not using the Jenkinsfile pipeline file, but instead executing a Shell within the Jenkins job to execute the Docker build command. (docker build -t latest-build .)

Comment: Thanks @Robert I removed the `AS final` to have just `FROM base`, however now the error has changed to `Cannot retrieve .Id from 'docker inspect base'`  I don't have inspect in my Dockerfile, but suspect there is still an issue with running `FROM base` ??  I'll take a look at the related issues.

Comment: One of those tickets mention a really weird workaround which is adding this "FROM scratch" at the very top of the Dockerfile, then prepend a space before each following "FROM". Can you please try it?

Comment: thanks, I tried this, however I still got the error `Cannot retrieve .Id from 'docker inspect base AS final' `, with both potential solutions (the FROM scratch, with the FROM indents, and the removal of AS final) ,  I get the error `Cannot retrieve .Id from 'docker inspect base'`

Comment: I got this working by not using the Jenkinsfile pipeline file, but instead executing a Shell within the Jenkins job to execute the Docker build command.

Comment: Worked just fine for me using the indexed `COPY --from=0`. Thanks!

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Docker Plugin version 1.1.6 and Docker pipeline version 1.18

Comment: Reproduced with Docker Pipeline `1.18` and fixed by simply removing `AS final`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting this problem because I'm using `--target=<foo>` to build my image only up to a certain point.

So my Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8 AS BUILD

.. do build ..

FROM openjdk:8

COPY --from=BUILD /myapp/bin my_jar_file
```

And my build with `docker.build(<tag>, "--target=BUILD .")` fails with:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot retrieve .Id from 'docker inspect openjdk:8'
```

This is because Jenkins is trying to inspect the second `FROM openjdk:8` in the Dockerfile, and because that target didn't run Docker didn't pull down that image and it's unavailable to `docker inspect`

I've got a bunch of workarounds available to me:

1. Ensure that image is available anyway by running `docker pull openjdk:8` before building
2. Remove `--target=BUILD` from my `docker.build` command and let it build the whole thing (not too big a deal for me as the build is the most expensive part)
3. Avoid using `docker.build` and just `sh "docker build --target=BUILD .`

At the moment I'm not sure which one I'll go with

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem with Docker 18.09, but I wasn't using a multi stage build. In my case, I was getting:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot retrieve .Id from 'docker inspect centos:7'
```

The first step in my Dockerfile was:

```
FROM centos:7
```

I was able to fix the problem with `docker pull centos:7`; after that, the Jenkins build was able to complete successfully.

Comment: This worked. To clarify as this answer is not as complete: You need to run 'docker pull...' in a different stage so that it runs before the agent directive if you are using different agents in stages. If you are using only one agent then I'd recommend you then look into using multiple agents to solve the issue by coupling it with this answer here.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above ideas works for my case, and I finally got it work as below pipeline without chaning anything on Dockerfile:

1. Hardcode the build tag like "latest",
2. Get your own tag via sh,
3. Push your image with the hardcoded tag first,
4. Push the image again with your customized tag.

```
def my_own_tag = "unknown"
my_own_tag = sh ( script: 'git tag | tail -n1', returnStdout: true ).trim()
docker_img = docker.build("latest")
docker_img.push("latest")
docker_img.push("${my_own_tag}")
```