# Jenkins pipeline - Cannot retrieve .Id from 'docker inspect my.docker.repo/centos7'

Tags: docker, jenkins

Our Jenkins server is running version 2.109.

Within a pipeline script I'm attempting to execute:
docker.build("my.docker.repo/backend")

The base image for this build is defined in the Dockerfile with:
FROM my.docker.repo/centos7

When I execute the build within Jenkins, the image is built and tagged as expected. But the Jenkins job fails with the error:
Cannot retrieve .Id from 'docker inspect my.docker.repo/centos7'

Subsequently I can navigate to the Jenkins server and the Id does show in the response returned by executing 'docker inspect my.docker.repo/centos7'.

I also have a second Docker repository hosted on a nexus server that we use for development. When I repeat the steps above, substituting my.docker.repo with my.nexus.repo, then the Jenkins job completes successfully.

I'm stuck trying to figure out why I'm getting this error when using the first repository but not the second. I know an can always run the docker build command using a  shell command within the pipeline script. But I'd like to figure out a solution to the problem described above.

Comment: Did you solve it ? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in the Jenkins plugin. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678535/how-to-resolve-cannot-retrieve-id-from-docker-when-building-docker-image-usin) for further details.

A workaround is avoiding `docker.build()` and using `docker build` command in a shell instead.